# Scroll through table rows programmatically

Tags: angularjs

The objective of [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yvn8Lyt3wdkUPCpti2y3?p=preview) is to have a table where the up and down keys will be used to select rows programmatically and scroll through the table. The selected row will have a different background color.

When keying up/down I use `e.preventDefault()` to avoid the rows to move up/down twice.  Problem is that when I start scrolling down the rows stay fixed and the selected row disappears. How to fix this?

HTML

```
<div id="selector" tabindex="0" ng-keydown="scroll($event)"
          style="width:300px;height:80px;border:1px solid gray;overflow-y:auto">
     <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td class="td1" ng-class="{'tdactive' : $index==index }">{{item.col}}</td>
            <td class="td1" ng-class="{'tdactive' : $index==index }">{{item.dsc}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

  document.getElementById("selector").focus();

  $scope.items = [ {col:"aaa", dsc:"AAA1"}, {col:"bbb", dsc:"BBB2"} , {col:"ccc", dsc:"CCC3"}, 
            {col:"aaa2", dsc:"AAA21"}, {col:"bbb2", dsc:"BBB22"} , {col:"ccc2", dsc:"CCC23"}, 
            {col:"aaa2", dsc:"AAA21"}, {col:"bbb2", dsc:"BBB22"} , {col:"ccc2", dsc:"CCC23"} ];
  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.scroll = function(e) {
      if (e.which === 40) { // down arrow
          if ($scope.index<$scope.items.length - 1)
              $scope.index++;
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      else if (e.which === 38) { // up arrow
          if ($scope.index>0)
              $scope.index--;
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to add table row id as `id="tr-{{$index}}"`

You can then prevent your scroll if tr is in the current viewport

```
$scope.scroll = function(e) {
    var parentContainer = document.getElementById("selector");
      if (e.which === 40) { // down arrow
          if ($scope.index<$scope.items.length - 1)
          {

          var element = document.getElementById("tr-"+$scope.index);
          if(isElementInViewport(parentContainer,element)){
            e.preventDefault();
          }

              $scope.index++;
          }
      }
      else if (e.which === 38) { // up arrow
          if ($scope.index>0)
          {
          var element = document.getElementById("tr-"+$scope.index);
          if(!isElementInViewport(parentContainer,element)){
            e.preventDefault();
          }
              $scope.index--;
          }
      }
  };

function isElementInViewport(parent, el) {
  if(parent==undefined || el==undefined)
  return false;
    var elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        parRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
        //console.log(elRect)
        //console.log(parRect)
        var elementHeight = elRect.height;
    return (
        elRect.top >= parRect.top &&
        elRect.bottom <= parRect.bottom &&
        elRect.bottom+elementHeight<= parRect.bottom
    );
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HiqH1e57iFtMzxZxhIqi?p=preview)

Comment: The problem that I see is that when the row selected is at the bottom of the table and you key down, then the next row should also be at the bottom of the table, but instead is at the middle. I tried changing the table height but it didn't work either.

Comment: check the updated plunker, if this is what you want?